# Why does input stream read data in chunks?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, inputstream

I am trying to read some data from a network socket using the following code -

```
Socket s = new Socket(address, 502);
response = new byte[1024];
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
int count = is.read(response, 0, 100);
```

The amount of data isn't large. It is 16 bytes in total. However the read() statement does not read all the data in one go. It reads only 8 bytes of data into my buffer.

I have to make multiple calls to read() like this in order to read the data -

```
Socket s = new Socket(address, 502);
response = new byte[1024];
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
int count = is.read(response, 0, 100);
count += is.read(response, count, 100-count);
```

Why is this happening? Why does read() not read the entire stream in one go?

*Please note that the data is not arriving gradually. If I wait for 2 seconds before reading the data by making a call to Thread.sleep(2000) the behavior remains the same.*

Comment: Typically you would use the result (in `count`) of the first call as offset (now hardcoded to `8`) in your second call (and do the call inside a while loop while checking for EOS).

Comment: @martijno I would. But that is not my confusion. Why is this happening?

Comment: What's at the other side of the socket? Something that you have control over?

Comment: @martijno Its a thermal sensor. It responds with 16 bytes of status data every time I poll it. I poll it by writing few bytes in OutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that it blocks until data arrives. "That in turn is because the data doesn't necessarily arrive all in one go." Why not is my question.

The data doesn't necessarily all arrive in one go because the network typically breaks it up into packets.  IP is a *packet switching* protocol.

> Does TCP transmit it blocks of 8 bytes?

Possibly, but probably not.  The packet size depends on the network / networks that the data has traversed, but a typical internet packet size is around 1500 bytes.

If you are getting 8 bytes at a time, either your data is either coming through a network with an unusually small packet size, or (more likely) the sender is sending the data 8 bytes at a time.  The second explanation more or less jives with what your other comments say.

> And since I explicitly specify 100, a number much larger than the data in buffer shouldn't it attempt to read up till atleast 100 bytes?

Well no.  It is not specified to work that way, and it doesn't work that way.  You need to write your code according to what the spec says.

---

It is possible that this has something to do with the way the device is being "polled".  But without looking at the specs for the device (or even knowing what it is exactly) this is only a guess.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative but that doesn't resolve my confusion. The network is a 100mbps Ethernet. So packet size should be considerably large. And if the device transmits slowly in chucks of 8 bytes then waiting 2 seconds with Thread.sleep(2000) should fill up the buffer don't you think?

Comment: @KshitizSharma - What I think is irrelevant.  What matters is what you see happening in practice.

Comment: @KshitizSharma In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice they are not. ;)

Answer (score 7):

> Why does read() not read the entire stream in one go?

Because it isn't specified to do so. See the Javadoc. It blocks until at least one byte is available, then returns some number between 1 and the supplied length, inclusive.

That in turn is because the data doesn't necessarily arrive all in one go. You have no control over how TCP sends and receives data. You are obliged to just treat it as a byte stream.

Comment: I understand that it blocks until data arrives. *"That in turn is because the data doesn't necessarily arrive all in one go."* Why not is my question. Does TCP transmit in blocks of 8 bytes? And since I explicitly specify 100, a number much larger than the data in buffer shouldn't it **attempt** to read up till atleast 100 bytes?

Comment: @KshitizSharma if 100 bytes are available in the receive buffer, it is likely to give you 100 bytes, if 8 bytes are available it will give you 8. If 1 byte is available, it will give you 1. If no bytes are available, it will block.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I understand how streams and buffers work. The stream returns only the available content in buffer. I get it. My question is about the behavior of the buffer. Why do only 8 bytes arrive on a 100mpbs TCP ethernet network?

Comment: @KshitizSharma Why **only and exactly** 8 bytes - by looking at how the data is being written to the stream you may be able to answer these questions. If you want to control (at least to have some control over) what and how you will read from InputStream you will need to wrap it in BufferedReader or similar...

Comment: @GermannArlington That wouldn't make the slightest difference, let alone give you any 'control'. Using a `BufferedOutputStream` or `BufferedWriter` at the *sender* might make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the data is arriving gradually not because of your reading but because of the sender.

The sender should use a [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) (in the middle) to make big chunks before sending (and use flush only when it's needed).